# Handling Font Cascade lists in CGFontRefs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, core-graphics

I am trying to implement a very specific animation in an iOS app, which requires me to be able to draw glyphs and glyph ranges individually with various properties. I am using an `NSLayoutManager` and the associated infrastructure to typeset these glyphs, then I use the `- [NSLayoutManager showCGGlyphs:positions:count:font:matrix:attributes:inContext:]` method to do the drawing.

This works perfectly for English, Russian, and certain other languages. However, for certain languages, like Korean or Arabic, I get garbage.

The problem seems to be the font I'm using. I am using the system font (Some variant of San Francisco, I believe, from `-[UIFont systemFontOfSize:]`). If I switch the font to "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium", the Korean Glyphs I expect are drawn.

In "high level" API like `UILabel`, fonts have a "cascade list" of fonts that provide glyphs for languages like Arabic. My conclusion is that the `CGFontRef` that I have to use to draw in the Core Graphics Context does not have access to this cascade list, and therefore it doesn't work properly.

It seems that there is some way to get this cascade list, because `-[NSLayoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:]` works perfectly, so it must somehow be using this feature.

My question is, is there a way to create a `CGFontRef` that has this list? If not, what is the best way to select the right font for each glyph?

Some of my code that demonstrates this issue, in the `drawInContext:` method of my `CALayer` is reproduced below:

```
NSRange range = [self.layoutManager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context)
                                                  inTextContainer:self.textContainer];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = self.layoutManager;
    NSMutableArray<NSValue *> *glyphs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray<NSValue *> *points = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = range.location; i < range.length; i++) {
      CGGlyph glyph = [layoutManager CGGlyphAtIndex:i]; /* in the real code, I use a category on NSLayoutManager to make this safe for iOS 8 and iOS 9 both, but it doesn't matter here */
      [glyphs addObject:[NSValue value:&glyph
                          withObjCType:@encode(CGGlyph)]];
      CGPoint fragmentLocation = [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:i
                                                                 effectiveRange:NULL].origin;
      CGPoint location = [layoutManager locationForGlyphAtIndex:i];
      [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.horizontalOffsetForText + fragmentLocation.x + location.x,
                                                              self.bounds.size.height - (fragmentLocation.y + location.y))]];
    }
    CGGlyph *rawGlyphs = malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph) * glyphs.count);
    CGPoint *rawPoints = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * points.count);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < glyphs.count; i++) {
      [glyphs[i] getValue:rawGlyphs + i];
      [points[i] getValue:rawPoints + i];
    }
    CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithFontName((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)self.font.fontName);
    CGContextSetFont(context, cgFont);
    CGContextSetFontSize(context, self.font.pointSize);
    CGAffineTransform t = CGContextGetTextMatrix(context);
    t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 1, -1);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, t);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.textColor.CGColor);
    [layoutManager showCGGlyphs:rawGlyphs
                      positions:rawPoints
                          count:glyphs.count
                           font:self.font
                         matrix:t
                     attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.textColor,
                                  NSFontAttributeName: self.font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: self.paragraphStyle}
                      inContext:context];
    free(rawGlyphs);
    free(rawPoints);
    CFRelease(cgFont);
```

Comment: Did you figure out the answer to this question? I'm facing a similar problem, and there's very little info available online.

Comment: I didn't. It's been two years, but I believe I did find a very ugly workaround, though, which was to use `CTFontCreateForString` on a per-glyph basis. https://github.com/fleksy/FLYAnimatedTextReplacementLabel/blob/master/FLYAnimatedTextReplacementLabel/FLYAnimatedTextReplacementLayer.m